# Error in connecting to mongodb cluster with replica sets in another host

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb

I have an `nodejs` application in staging environment which need a MongoDB replication set to run. I have created my MongoDB instance like below:

```
$ mongod --port 27017 --replSet rs0 --dbpath /data/db1 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
$ mongod --port 27018 --replSet rs0 --dbpath /data/db2 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
$ mongod --port 27019 --replSet rs0 --dbpath /data/db2 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

and set db1 as primary. the application also running in the same host and connect to the database like this:

```
const { connectionString, replicaSet } = config.mongodb;

try {
  mongoose
    .connect(
      connectionString,
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        replicaSet,
      },
    )
    .then(() => mongoose.connection.db.admin().command({ setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: '4.0' }));
```

which `connectionString` is: `mongodb://localhost:27017/x`.
now I running application in my machine and want to connect it to host database so I change connectionString to: `mongodb://172.16.25.66:27017/x` but `MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27019] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27019]` I am confused, why its logged `127.0.0.1:29019`? I think it should be the host IP address not local?
how can fix this so that I could connect to staging host MongoDB with application in local?

**Edit**:

if Ip put `console.log(connecitonString)` in above code the result would be same as the input.
But I figured out something interesting, when I delete `replicaSet` option in `connect` function it works ok! can anybody explain this?

Comment: try `console.log(connectionString)` inside the try block, and post the result